# JQuery setTimeout doesn't work for some reason

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm still new to JQuery, I used setTimeout  to load the inserted data after certain time.  I tried the examples  as well as the answers about this issue but nothing worked!

What I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function fetch_data(){

            $.ajax({
                url:"getdata.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $('.result').html(data);
                }

            });
        }
        fetch_data();

        setTimeout(function() {
            fetch_data();
        }, 2000);


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code above is working as it is written, it immediately calls `fetch_data` then calls it again after 2 seconds

Comment: It works fine. Do you include jQuery library?

Comment: How are you expecting it to work?  It looks fine.

Comment: If you want it to repeat every 2s then you need to put setTimeout inside the function. Btw. `setTimeout(fetch_data, 2000);` does the same without creating a superfluous function.

Comment: @jack is your response  a JSON object??

Comment: @maraca . nah, use `setInterval instead`

Comment: What I'm doing is  adding new records to database, but I  get nothing unless I refresh the page.  No not "JSON "

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali I disagree... what if the request takes longer than 2s to complete? You are stacking up requests. Like that you minimize the workload for the server.... and sorry, `setTimeout` needs to go into the end of `success`

Comment: Yeahh setInterval  worked, but what the difference ?

Comment: setInterval repeats.  seTimeout fires once only after a delay.

Comment: @jack if it's not JSON what exactly is your response? a text? please show us. Thanks

Comment: @maraca, and what is the difference if using setTimeout? `If you want it to repeat every 2s then you need to put setTimeout`, for repeating request, setInterval should handle it. If you talk about `request takes longer than 2s to complete`, then you should narrow down the Promise

Comment: So setTimeout repeats it once.  Thanks ^^

Comment: @HenryDev   I had to use setInterval that was my mistake, it's not data type issue.    Thank you for help. I appreciate that

Comment: @jack Glad I could help :)

Comment: @jack I'm updating my answer then.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali No, you are stacking up requests if you lose connection... but not if you call a setTimeout of 2s *after* the request *completes*... (success is not optimal too...) instead of just firing wildly every 2s without taking into account how long requests take.

Comment: @maraca, oh yeah. You're right about that. But that's not applicable for this use case. What about if the insert process is doing at another place using simple form action instead of AJAX request, and the polling request were done at another place to keep it up to date. So how to call it inside success/complete callback, that way, you need the setInterva function, or just go to websocket instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `setInterval`. Here's the code you will need.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function fetch_data(){

        $.ajax({
            url:"getdata.php",
            success: function(data){
                $('.result').html(data);
            }

        });
    }
    fetch_data();

    setInterval(function() {
        fetch_data();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is correct.
I think the problem is in jQuery.ajax call, so I think it returns "failed".
Please add "error" method and test it out as following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function fetch_data(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"getdata.php",
            success: function(data){
                $('.result').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('request failed');
            }
        });
    }

    fetch_data();

    setTimeout(function() {
        fetch_data();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seams okay. 
But in your code `fetch_data` function will get called twice.

IF you only need to call `fetch_data` after 2 second. Remove the `fetch_data();` call after declaration.

The following sample will explain it clearly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function fetch_data(){
    $('#message').append('<p>called fetch</p>');
  }

  fetch_data();

  setTimeout(function() {
    fetch_data();
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"></div>
```

As mentioned in the above answers, it could be issue of failing ajax request. So make sure ajax call works fine.